# R - create row duplicates for every value of a class variable

Tags: r

I am trying to recreate a process I have in SAS in R, where I create a dataset with different values of a certain variable to score on that variable. In this case, I want every observation in my dataset to be repeated, with treatment ordinal changing from 0 to 4, so each observation will turn into 5 observations.

SAS code:

```
data want;
  set have;
  do treatmentordinal=0 to 4;
  output;
  end;
run;
```

This will basically create 5 observations for every observation in the dataset, where treatment ordinal will go from 0 to 4 . I have been searching for how to do this and can't find anything.

To be clear, I already have a dataset with 10k or so rows. Just want to have each row have every value of treatment.

Example
have:

```
treatment=c(2)
ID=c(1)
df_have=data.frame(treatment,ID)
```

want:

```
treatment2=c(0,1,2,3,4)
ID=c(1)
df_want=data.frame(treatment2,ID)
```

Comment: `data.frame(treatment = 0:4, ID=1)` ? or use `transform(df_have[rep(1, 5),], treatment = seq(5)-1)`

Comment: I guess thats another way for my example, though I want to apply something to a dataset already made.

Comment: Please check the edit in my previous comment

Comment: Hmm, I see the intent, and I am trying to figure out what to change, but right now it just does it for the first observation in the df_have dataset, so I end up with a dataset of 5 total observations

Comment: @AdamSanders does your data have a unique `id` ? do you want to replicte each row for that unique id?

Comment: it does have a unique ID for each row, called ID

Comment: anyways, got this solution working, rep(1:nrow(df),times=5), thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `expand.grid`

```
treatment2=c(0,1,2,3,4)
ID=c(1:2)
expand.grid(TR=treatment2,ID=ID)
      TR   ID
1     0    1
2     1    1
3     2    1
4     3    1
5     4    1
6     0    2
7     1    2
8     2    2
9     3    2
10    4    2
```

On your main data, you could probably do something like:

```
expand.grid(TR=unique(data$treatment), ID=unique(data$ID))
```